# Don't want to dismiss popover in Titanium when user touches outside of the popover

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, popover

I'm just started working in Titanium. And now working on popover in titanium, using the following code.

```
var myPopover = Ti.UI.iPad.createPopover({ height: 150, width: 150 });
popover.add(view);
popover.show({ view: button });
```

My issue is when user touches outside of the popover the popover is dismissing (default behaviour), I don't want that.

In iOS there is a delegate method called: `- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` . If we don't want to dismiss the popover when user touches outside just return `NO`, is there any way to do this in **Titanium** ? 
I read the [**Titanium.UI.iPad.Popover**](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPad.Popover) documentataion, but couldn't find any such methods.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately without significant work yourself you won't be able to in the short-term.

Some tips:

Don't trust the api docs to have everything in. Instead either look through the SDK in Github or find the SDK on your system and search through the iOS (in the iPhone folder) classes for this method.

If you go to appcelerator's JIRA account, you can request this to be implemented. Go to the Q&A and make some noise about it to get other people to watch the JIRA issue so it is prioritised by Appcelerator.

You could write a module that extends the popover functionality, in fact with modules you can extend anything and create the javascript bridge yourself so you can access any properties or anything you want. There's guides for that on the Wiki..

Happy hunting ;)

Comment: I got an answer from Titanium forum. You can check it here http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146322/dont-want-to-dismiss-popover-in-titanium

Comment: Interesting answer, that didn't used to work, might look into using that ;)